# How to make sql table with a column named repeat? Needed for a Django app

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Python app using Django CMS and a sql db.  My localhost version uses a sqlite db but I am trying to import my local DB into a SQL db for the production version.  However I am getting an error in my .sql file I exported for my GUI.

The offending code is here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cmsplugin_css_background_filercssbackground (
  cmsplugin_ptr_id INT NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  repeat VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  attachment VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  bg_position VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  forced bool NOT NULL,
  image_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(cmsplugin_ptr_id) REFERENCES cms_cmsplugin(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(cmsplugin_ptr_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(image_id) REFERENCES filer_image(file_ptr_id)
);
```

The error is

```
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'repeat    VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    attachment  VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    bg_position VARCH' at line 4
```

It seems to be this line causing the error `repeat VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,`
I know the keyword `repeat` is sometime used in SQL so I tihnk that might the issue, can I create a column called `repeat` and if not how I fix this?

Comment: `repeat` is a MySQL Reserved word, I suggest you pick another name

Comment: And if this is a question about `MySQL` **why have you added a SQLServer and SQLite tag**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did not name the column Django did, can Django be used with a SQL db or Do I need to use sqlite?

Comment: THen you will have to wrap the column name `repeat` in backticks like `\`repeat\` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,` And also in every query you write, but that is just good practice anyway

Comment: I'm with RiggsFolly on this, it is good practice to delimit your field names anyway. I mean try to reasonably avoid using reserved and keywords (especially the common ones for general readability, no one likes reading `SELECT \`select\` FROM ...`); but always delimiting provides a consistent style and guards you from when the rare times MySQL adds new key/reserved words could overlap with a column name you've previously used.

Comment: Django auto quotes reserved keywords in the migration.